# WPF Custom Usercontrol to show and edit generic struct

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, struct, reflection

I am working a lot with network protocols and very frequently that means visualizing data i received over the network. The format is always defined by a struct, and the byte array received over the network is converted into saied struct. For the past two days i tried to implement a control that automatically generates a view, that is capable of showing all structs and their properties recursively.

Example struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct sImageDimension
{
    public ushort Width { get; set; }
    public ushort Height { get; set; }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct sVideoFormat
{
    public byte videoFormatEnabled { get; set; }
    public byte transmissionMethod { get; set; }
    public ushort transmissionCycle { get; set; }
    public sImageDimension WidthAndHeight { get; set; }
    public uint frameRate { get; set; }
    public byte Interlaced { get; set; }
    public byte colourSpace { get; set; }
    public uint maxBitrate { get; set; }
    public byte videoCompression { get; set; }
}
```

My Implementation is able to show the struct as intended

[image]

My problem lies in editing the values. If i Update a textbox that was created for one of the nested struct properties I cannot manage to find the right object to update to make it work recursivly for nested structs. In this specific example if I update with and Hight, the value changes will not be applied to the struct and only show in the textboxes.
I am really struggeling with Reflection and the abstract nature of this problem.

Please find my implementation below:

MainWindow:

```
<local:StructEditor StructInstance="{Binding RequestPayload, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource StructToByteArray}}"/>
<!-- For reproduction just bind it to an instance of the struct-->
<local:StructEditor StructInstance="{Binding ViewModelStructInstance}"/>
 <!-- second editor to see if the values were updated-->
<local:StructEditor StructInstance="{Binding ViewModelStructInstance}"/>
```

Usercontrol:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SomeIPTester.StructEditor"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SomeIPTester"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Border BorderBrush="HotPink" BorderThickness="5">

            <Grid>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="stackPanel" Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ScrollViewer>

</UserControl>
```

Usercontrol Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SomeIPTester
{
    public partial class StructEditor : UserControl
    {
        public StructEditor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StructInstanceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("StructInstance", typeof(object), typeof(StructEditor), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnStructInstanceChanged));

        public object StructInstance
        {
            get { return GetValue(StructInstanceProperty); }
            set 
            { 
                SetValue(StructInstanceProperty, value);
                MethodInfo method = typeof(NetworkByteOrderConverter).GetMethod("StructureToByteArray").MakeGenericMethod(TargetType);
            }
        }



        public Type TargetType
        {
            get { return (Type)this.GetValue(TargetTypeProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(TargetTypeProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TargetType.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetTypeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(TargetType), typeof(Type), typeof(StructEditor), new PropertyMetadata(default(Type)));


        static byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
        {
            // Remove any spaces and convert the hex string to a byte array
            hexString = hexString.Replace(" ", "");
            int length = hexString.Length / 2;
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[length];

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                byteArray[i] = System.Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
            }

            return byteArray;
        }

        private static void OnStructInstanceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is StructEditor structEditor && e.NewValue != null)
            {
                structEditor.GenerateControls();
            }
        }

        private void GenerateControls()
        {
            stackPanel.Children.Clear();

            if (StructInstance != null)
            {
                DisplayPropertiesRecursively(StructInstance, depth: 0);
            }
        }

        private void DisplayPropertiesRecursively(object instance, int depth)
        {
            Type type = instance.GetType();
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
            {
                StackPanel fieldPanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };

                // Label to display property name with indentation based on depth
                Label label = new Label { Content = $"{new string(' ', depth * 2)}{property.Name}", Width = 100 };
                fieldPanel.Children.Add(label);

                // TextBox for editing property value
                TextBox textBox = new TextBox
                {
                    Width = 100,
                    Text = property.GetValue(instance)?.ToString() ?? string.Empty
                };

                // Handle changes in TextBox
                textBox.TextChanged += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    // Update property when TextBox changes
                    try
                    {
                        object value = Convert.ChangeType(textBox.Text, property.PropertyType);
                        property.SetValue(instance, value);

                        // Manually trigger the update of the binding source
                        UpdateBindingSourceRecursively(instance, property.Name);
                        this.StructInstance = StructInstance;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        
                    }
                };

                fieldPanel.Children.Add(textBox);
                stackPanel.Children.Add(fieldPanel);

                // Recursively display properties for nested structs or objects
                if (!property.PropertyType.IsPrimitive && property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
                {
                    object nestedInstance = property.GetValue(instance);
                    if (nestedInstance != null && !IsEnumerableType(property.PropertyType))
                    {
                        DisplayPropertiesRecursively(nestedInstance, depth + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private bool IsEnumerableType(Type type)
        {
            return typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type);
        }

        private void UpdateBindingSourceRecursively(object instance, string propertyName)
        {
            Type type = instance.GetType();
            PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);

            // Manually trigger the update of the binding source for the current property
            var textBox = FindTextBoxByPropertyName(stackPanel, propertyName);
            var bindingExpression = textBox?.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
            bindingExpression?.UpdateSource();

            // Recursively update the binding source for properties of properties
            if (!property.PropertyType.IsPrimitive && property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
            {
                object nestedInstance = property.GetValue(instance);
                if (nestedInstance != null)
                {
                    DisplayPropertiesRecursively(nestedInstance, depth: 1);
                }
            }
        }

        private TextBox FindTextBoxByPropertyName(StackPanel panel, string propertyName)
        {
            foreach (var child in panel.Children)
            {
                if (child is StackPanel fieldPanel)
                {
                    foreach (var fieldChild in fieldPanel.Children)
                    {
                        if (fieldChild is TextBox textBox)
                        {
                            var label = fieldPanel.Children[0] as Label;
                            if (label?.Content.ToString().Trim() == propertyName)
                            {
                                return textBox;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope somebody more skilled can show me what i am missing...

Comment: The problem is `public sImageDimension WidthAndHeight { get; }` returns a copy of the value. To update anything within that struct you will need to call `public sImageDimension WidthAndHeight { set; }` to replace the entire value.

Comment: I understand, but i dont understand how i could work around this while still keeping it a gerneric solution that will work with different types of structs

Comment: You need to hook together some kind of change notification event, so whenever you edit a field a parent object can listen to the event and call the setter, triggering it's own change event... Or ignore properties and set the raw backing fields behind them.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman my problem is once i go down recursivly because its a getbyValue thing i lose the reference to its parent...The "some kind of" part is what i am struggeling with. I am used to work with classes and objects. Reflection makes this so much harder to see through...

Comment: @DenisSchaf I have completed my answer to address your last comment (still a conceptual code, though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are overcomplicating things. This is a trivial problem and you really made it look complicated. You should not bother with handling any UI elements inside your control. We are presenting data models. A list of properties or key-value pairs. So, we should look to use an `ItemsControl` and leverage templating to create a fully dynamic view without caring about visual details when implementing the logic of the editor. We just need a `TextBlock` and a `TextBox` to present an item. Can't get much more trivial.

The caveat is that structs are value types and structs are always copied by value.
This means, that the value received via data binding is not the value of the data source but a copy: binding target and binding source operate on different instances.
Hence, we have to force a property update to allow the binding source to fetch the new copy of the edited object.
We also have to consider this fact when modifying properties that are themselves a value type.
This boils down to the fact that every change must end with a replacement of the original source value.

Then to dynamically generate the view, we use a `TreeView` that shows data items for each property and field. We host this `TreeView` inside a custom control.

Performance is critical as we make heavy use of reflection (any suggestions to improve the performance are welcome).
For example, we can store values retrieved for the type in the internal data models to avoid invoking reflection multiple times only to get the same value. We can also avoid multiple enumerations by implementing generators (use yield return).

Another minor problem is the fact that value types are implicitly boxed but have to be unboxed explicitly: the `TwoWay` binding won't work on structs as the binding engine does not perform this explicit type cast.
The following example unboxes the struct (when updating the binding source) by injecting an `IValueConverter` (if no converter was defined by the client).
This way we can perform a generic unboxing type cast without having to bother the client with that task. This adds convenience to how the editor must be used.

To implement the example I have used and modified existing code. So you get some extras for free.

The key components:

- The `MemberItem` is the actual representation of an edited member of the edited value type object (or reference type object). Even a reference type can define value type properties. Therefore, we have to treat reference types and value types equally in terms of presentation and updated member value propagation to the original edited object. The properties and fields of the edited object are extracted and wrapped into the `MemberItem` for presentation.
- `GenericUnboxingValueConverter` is the generic `IValueConverter` used to unbox the changed object
- `TypeEditorControl` is the actual control to edit both value type and reference type objects. By default, it allows to edit all public properties and fields if they are not read-only. Setting `TypeEditorControl.IsEditReadOnlyMembersAllowedProperty` to `true` allows to edit public read-only fields and properties too. The `TypeEditorControl` uses reflection to analyze the edited object and creates a tree data structure to present the editable object.

[image]

### Implementation

**UnboxConverter.cs**
Helper class to provide a generic way of casting.

```cs
public class UnboxConverter
{
  public static TStruct Unbox<TStruct>(object boxedValue)
    => (TStruct)boxedValue;
}
```

**GenericUnboxingValueConverter.cs**
The `IValueConverter` implementation that actually performs the unboxing of the target value of type `object` based on a `Type` parameter.

```cs
public class GenericUnboxingValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
  private static Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> UnboxingConverterTableInternal { get; }
    = new Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();

  // Make converters globally available, but restrict modification access.
  public static readonly ReadOnlyDictionary<Type, MethodInfo> UnboxingConverterTable { get; }
    = new ReadOnlyDictionary<Type, MethodInfo>(GenericUnboxingValueConverter.UnboxingConverterTableInternal);

  // Implicit boxing --> pass through
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    => value; 

  // Explicit unboxing using the generic UnboxConverter
  public object? ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    bool valueIsReferencetype = !value.GetType().IsValueType;
    if (valueIsReferencetype)
    {
      // No explicit cast required.  
      // We can safely avoid the reflection to improve performance.
      return value;
    }

    // To improve performance, we store the created MethodInfo 
    // in a global table.
    // This reduces the costs of reflection as it is now only required once per type.
    if (!GenericUnboxingValueConverter.UnboxingConverterTable.TryGetValue(targetType, out MethodInfo genericUnboxMethodInfo))
    {    
      Type unboxConverterTypeInfo = typeof(UnboxConverter);
      MethodInfo? unboxMethodInfo = unboxConverterTypeInfo.GetMethod(nameof(UnboxConverter.Unbox));    
      genericUnboxMethodInfo = unboxMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(targetType);
      GenericUnboxingValueConverter.UnboxingConverterTableInternal.Add(targetType, genericUnboxMethodInfo);
    }

    return genericUnboxMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new[] { value });
  }
}
```

**MemberItem.cs**
The abstract base class to present editable properties and fields.
This item is the actual item that is displayed in the `TreeView`.
The class stores all meta info obtained via reflection to improve performance.

```cs
public abstract class MemberItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public MemberItem(MemberItem? parentMemberItem, string memberName, object? memberValue, Type memberType, Type declaringType, object declaringInstance)
  {
    this.ParentMemberItem = parentMemberItem;
    this.Name = memberName;
    this.Value = memberValue;
    this.Type = memberType;
    this.IsValueIConvertibleImplementation = this.Type.GetInterface(nameof(IConvertible)) is not null;
    this.ShortTypeName = this.Type.Name!;
    this.FullyQualifiedTypeName = this.Type.FullName!;
    this.IsDeclaringTypeValueType = declaringType.IsValueType;
    this.DeclaringInstance = declaringInstance;
    this.NestedMembers = new ObservableCollection<MemberItem>();
  }

  protected abstract void UpdateValueFromTypeInfo();


  // For example, when the edited value of this underlying member was changed outside this editor, 
  // we have to update the item models in the TreeView. 
  // Then this method is called.
  // Because the values can include value types, 
  // we have to recursively update the reference tree of the current member.
  public void UpdateValue(bool isUpdateNestedMembersEnabled)
  {
    UpdateValueFromTypeInfo();
    if (isUpdateNestedMembersEnabled)
    {
      foreach (MemberItem nestedMember in this.NestedMembers)
      {
        nestedMember.DeclaringInstance = this.Value;
        nestedMember.UpdateValue(isUpdateNestedMembersEnabled: true);
      }
    }
  }

  public void AddNestedMembers(IEnumerable<MemberItem> nestedMemberItems)
  {
    foreach (MemberItem nestedMemeberItem in nestedMemberItems)
    {
      this.NestedMembers.Add(nestedMemeberItem);
    }
  }

  // Converts the string received from XAML (user input fields) back to the original type
  // TODO::Implement input validation to avoid an invalid cast exception
  // (for example, when an integer input field receives alphabetic input).
  public bool TryGetConvertedValue(out object? convertedValue)
  {
    convertedValue = null;

    if (this.Value is null)
    {
      return true;
    }

    if (this.IsValueIConvertibleImplementation)
    {
      // Use Convert.ChangeType to avoid additional reflection.
      //
      // TODO::Implement input validation to avoid an invalid cast exception
      // or overflow exception for integer types etc.
      convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(this.Value, this.Type);
      return true;
    }

    // Try to use a TypeConverter (involves additional reflection).
    //
    // TODO::Implement input validation to avoid unexpected behavior
    // from the user perspective, because changes are displayed but were not comitted
    // due to the skipped conversion for the case the TypeConverter.IsValid() retuens FALSE).
    TypeConverter typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this.Type);
    if (!typeConverter.IsValid(this.Value)
      || !typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(this.Value.GetType()))
    {
      return false;
    }

    convertedValue = typeConverter.ConvertFrom(this.Value);
    return true;
  }

  private void OnValueChanged()
    => this.ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

  private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
  public event EventHandler? ValueChanged;

  public MemberItem? ParentMemberItem { get; }
  public string Name { get; }
  public string ShortTypeName { get; }

  // Excluding the assembly name
  public string FullyQualifiedTypeName { get; }

  public Type Type { get; }
  public object DeclaringInstance { get; private set; }
  public bool IsDeclaringTypeValueType { get; }
  public bool IsValueIConvertibleImplementation { get; }
  public ObservableCollection<MemberItem> NestedMembers { get; }

  private object? value;
  public object? Value
  {
    get => this.value;
    set
    {
      this.value = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
      OnValueChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

**PropertyItem.cs**
Item to display an editable property.

```cs
public class PropertyItem : MemberItem
{
  public PropertyItem(MemberItem? parentMemberItem, object declaringInstance, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    : base(parentMemberItem, propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(declaringInstance), propertyInfo.PropertyType, propertyInfo.DeclaringType, declaringInstance)
  {
    this.PropertyInfo = propertyInfo;
  }

  // For example, when the property value of the underlying type 
  // was changed outside this editor, 
  // we have to update the item models in the TreeView. 
  // Then this method is called by the MemberItem base.
  protected override void UpdateValueFromTypeInfo()
  {
    this. Value = this.PropertyInfo.GetValue(this.DeclaringInstance);
  }

  public PropertyInfo PropertyInfo { get; set; }
}
```

**FieldItem.cs**
Item to display an editable field.

```cs
public class FieldItem : MemberItem
{
  public FieldItem(MemberItem? parentMemberItem, object declaringInstance, FieldInfo fieldInfo)
    : base(parentMemberItem, fieldInfo.Name, fieldInfo.GetValue(declaringInstance), fieldInfo.FieldType, fieldInfo.DeclaringType, declaringInstance)
  {
    this.FieldInfo = fieldInfo;
  }

  // For example, when the field value of the underlying type 
  // was changed outside this editor, 
  // we have to update the item models in the TreeView. 
  // Then this method is called by the MemberItem base.
  protected override void UpdateValueFromTypeInfo()
    => this.Value = this.FieldInfo.GetValue(this.DeclaringInstance);

  public FieldInfo FieldInfo { get; set; }
}
```

**TypeEditorControl.cs**

```cs
public class TypeEditorControl : Control
{
  #region ValueProperty
  public object Value
  {
    get => (object)GetValue(ValueProperty);
    set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Value",
    typeof(object),
    typeof(TypeEditorControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
      default(object),
      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
      OnValueChanged,
      null,
      false,
      UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit));

  private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    => ((TypeEditorControl)d).OnValueChanged(e.OldValue, e.NewValue);

  #endregion ValueProperty

  #region MemberItemsProperty

  public ObservableCollection<MemberItem> MemberItems
  {
    get => (ObservableCollection<MemberItem>)GetValue(MemberItemsProperty);
    set => SetValue(MemberItemsPropertyKey, value);
  }

  private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey MemberItemsPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
    "MemberItems",
    typeof(ObservableCollection<MemberItem>),
    typeof(TypeEditorControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public static readonly DependencyProperty MemberItemsProperty = MemberItemsPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

  #endregion MemberItemsProperty

  #region EditedTypeNameProperty

  public string EditedTypeName
  {
    get => (string)GetValue(EditedTypeNameProperty);
    set => SetValue(EditedTypeNamePropertyKey, value);
  }

  private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey EditedTypeNamePropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
    "EditedTypeName",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(TypeEditorControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public static readonly DependencyProperty EditedTypeNameProperty = EditedTypeNamePropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

  #endregion EditedTypeNameProperty

  #region IsEditReadOnlyMembersAllowedProperty

  public bool IsEditReadOnlyMembersAllowed
  {
    get => (bool)GetValue(IsEditReadOnlyMembersAllowedProperty);
    set => SetValue(IsEditReadOnlyMembersAllowedProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEditReadOnlyMembersAllowedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
"IsEditReadOnlyMembersAllowed",
typeof(bool),
typeof(TypeEditorControl),
new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnIsEditReadOnlyMembersAllowedChanged));

  private static void OnIsEditReadOnlyMembersAllowedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    => ((TypeEditorControl)d).OnIsEditReadOnlyMembersAllowedChanged((bool)e.OldValue, (bool)e.NewValue);

  #endregion IsEditReadOnlyMembersAllowedProperty

  private Type? TypeOfEditingValue { get; set; }
  private Dictionary<string, MemberItem> PropertyNameToMemberItemMap { get; }
  private bool IsChangeSourceInternal { get; set; }
  private BindingExpression ValuePropertyBindingExpression { get; set; }

  static TypeEditorControl()
  {
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TypeEditorControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TypeEditorControl)));
  }

  public TypeEditorControl()
  {
    this.MemberItems = new ObservableCollection<MemberItem>();
    this.PropertyNameToMemberItemMap = new Dictionary<string, MemberItem>();
    this.IsChangeSourceInternal = false;
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
  }

  protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnInitialized(e);

    BindingBase originalValuePropertyBindingBase = BindingOperations.GetBindingBase(this, ValueProperty);

    // If the binding object is not a Binding (e.g., a MultiBinding) or already has an IValueConverter assigned we do nothing
    if (originalValuePropertyBindingBase is not Binding originalValuePropertyBinding
      || originalValuePropertyBinding.Converter is not null)
    {
      // Custom IValueConverter defined by client. Don't override
      return;
    }

    // While boxing is implicit, unboxing is always an explicit cast.
    // In order to return an object to a value type property we must unbox the value.
    // We can achieve this using an IValueConverter.
    //
    // For convenience, those details are hidden from the client.
    // Instead we take care of the unboxing by injecting a generic type converter into the binding.
    // To acomplish this we have to clone the original binding as it was already sealed by the binding engine at this point.
    Binding clonedValuePropertBinding = CloneObject(originalValuePropertyBinding);
    clonedValuePropertBinding.Converter = new GenericUnboxingValueConverter();
    _ = SetBinding(ValueProperty, clonedValuePropertBinding);
    this.ValuePropertyBindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(this, ValueProperty);
  }

  private static TObject CloneObject<TObject>(TObject originalValuePropertyBinding)
  {
    string serializedBindingInstance = XamlWriter.Save(originalValuePropertyBinding);
    var clonedValuePropertBinding = (TObject)XamlReader.Parse(serializedBindingInstance);
    return clonedValuePropertBinding;
  }

  private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    => this.ValuePropertyBindingExpression.UpdateSource();

  protected virtual void OnValueChanged(object oldValue, object newValue)
  {
    if (this.IsChangeSourceInternal)
    {
      return;
    }

    // Stop tracking changes (in case the edited value got modified outside while being edited) of the old value
    if (this.Value is INotifyPropertyChanged oldINotifyPropertyChangedImplementation)
    {
      oldINotifyPropertyChangedImplementation.PropertyChanged -= OnEditedItemPropertyChanged;
    }

    this.Value = newValue;
    if (this.Value is null)
    {
      return;
    }

    this.TypeOfEditingValue = this.Value.GetType();
    this.EditedTypeName = this.TypeOfEditingValue.FullName ?? string.Empty;

    // Track changes in case the edited value got modified outside while being edited
    if (this.Value is INotifyPropertyChanged newINotifyPropertyChangedImplementation)
    {
      newINotifyPropertyChangedImplementation.PropertyChanged += OnEditedItemPropertyChanged;
    }

    GenerateEditableItems();
  }

  private void OnEditedItemPropertyChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.IsChangeSourceInternal)
    {
      return;
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.PropertyName))
    {
      GenerateEditableItems();
      return;
    }

    if (this.PropertyNameToMemberItemMap.TryGetValue(e.PropertyName, out MemberItem propertyItem))
    {
      this.IsChangeSourceInternal = true;
      propertyItem.UpdateValue(isUpdateNestedMembersEnabled: true);
      this.IsChangeSourceInternal = false;
    }
  }

  protected virtual void OnIsEditReadOnlyMembersAllowedChanged(bool oldValue, bool newValue)
    => GenerateEditableItems();

  private void GenerateEditableItems()
  {
    this.MemberItems.Clear();
    this.PropertyNameToMemberItemMap.Clear();

    if (this.Value is null)
    {
      return;
    }

    IEnumerable<MemberItem> memberItems = EnumerateGeneratedMemberItemTree(null, this.TypeOfEditingValue, this.Value);
    foreach (MemberItem memberItem in memberItems)
    {
      this.MemberItems.Add(memberItem);
      if (memberItem is PropertyItem)
      {
        this.PropertyNameToMemberItemMap.Add(memberItem.Name, memberItem);
      }
    }
  }

  private IEnumerable<MemberItem> EnumerateGeneratedMemberItemTree(MemberItem? parentMemberItem, Type declaringtype, object declaringInstance)
  {
    PropertyInfo[] publicPropertyInfos = declaringtype.GetProperties();
    foreach (MemberItem memberItem in EnumerateGeneratedPropertyItems(publicPropertyInfos, declaringInstance, parentMemberItem))
    {
      yield return memberItem;
    }

    FieldInfo[] publicFieldInfos = declaringtype.GetFields();
    foreach (MemberItem memberItem in EnumerateGeneratedFieldItems(publicFieldInfos, declaringInstance, parentMemberItem))
    {
      yield return memberItem;
    }
  }

  private IEnumerable<MemberItem> EnumerateGeneratedPropertyItems(PropertyInfo[] publicPropertyInfos, object declaringInstance, MemberItem? parentMemberItem)
  {
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in publicPropertyInfos)
    {
      bool isPropertyReadOnly = propertyInfo.GetSetMethod(this.IsEditReadOnlyMembersAllowed) is null;
      if (isPropertyReadOnly)
      {
        continue;
      }

      var newPropertyItem = new PropertyItem(parentMemberItem, declaringInstance, propertyInfo);
      Type propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
      IEnumerable<MemberItem> nestedPropertyItems = Enumerable.Empty<MemberItem>();

      if (!propertyType.IsPrimitive && propertyType != typeof(string))
      {
        object declaringInstanceOfNestedType = propertyInfo.GetValue(declaringInstance);
        nestedPropertyItems = EnumerateGeneratedMemberItemTree(newPropertyItem, propertyType, declaringInstanceOfNestedType);
      }

      newPropertyItem.AddNestedMembers(nestedPropertyItems);
      newPropertyItem.ValueChanged += OnMemberValueChanged;

      yield return newPropertyItem;
    }
  }

  private IEnumerable<MemberItem> EnumerateGeneratedFieldItems(FieldInfo[] publicFieldInfos, object declaringInstance, MemberItem? parentMemberItem)
  {
    foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in publicFieldInfos)
    {
      if (!this.IsEditReadOnlyMembersAllowed
        && fieldInfo.IsInitOnly)
      {
        continue;
      }

      var newFieldItem = new FieldItem(parentMemberItem, declaringInstance, fieldInfo);
      Type fieldType = fieldInfo.FieldType;
      IEnumerable<MemberItem> nestedFieldItems = Enumerable.Empty<MemberItem>();

      if (!fieldType.IsPrimitive && fieldType != typeof(string))
      {
        object declaringInstanceOfNestedType = fieldInfo.GetValue(declaringInstance);
        nestedFieldItems = EnumerateGeneratedMemberItemTree(newFieldItem, fieldType, declaringInstanceOfNestedType);
      }

      newFieldItem.AddNestedMembers(nestedFieldItems);
      newFieldItem.ValueChanged += OnMemberValueChanged;

      yield return newFieldItem;
    }
  }

  private void OnMemberValueChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.IsChangeSourceInternal)
    {
      return;
    }

    var memberItem = (MemberItem)sender;
    if (!memberItem.TryGetConvertedValue(out object? convertedValue))
    {
      return;
    }

    this.IsChangeSourceInternal = true;

    if (memberItem is PropertyItem propertyItem)
    {
      propertyItem.PropertyInfo.SetValue(propertyItem.DeclaringInstance, convertedValue);
    }
    else if (memberItem is FieldItem fieldItem)
    {
      fieldItem.FieldInfo.SetValue(fieldItem.DeclaringInstance, convertedValue);
    }

    if (memberItem.IsDeclaringTypeValueType)
    {
      // If the member type is a value type,
      // then the declaring owner still contains the original copy as value.
      // We have to update it with the "modified" value (the new copy).
      // As we don't know if the parent tree does not have another value type member,
      // we have to traverse the complete member tree.
      UpdateParentsRecursive(memberItem);
    }

    OnEditedInstanceChanged();

    this.IsChangeSourceInternal = false;
  }

  private void UpdateParentsRecursive(MemberItem memberItem)
  {
    if (memberItem.ParentMemberItem is null)
    {
      return;
    }

    MemberItem parentOwner = memberItem.ParentMemberItem;
    object newValue = memberItem.DeclaringInstance;
    if (parentOwner is PropertyItem parentPropertyItem)
    {
      parentPropertyItem.PropertyInfo.SetValue(parentPropertyItem.DeclaringInstance, newValue);
    }
    else if (parentOwner is FieldItem parentFieldItem)
    {
      parentFieldItem.FieldInfo.SetValue(parentFieldItem.DeclaringInstance, newValue);
    }

    UpdateParentsRecursive(parentOwner);
  }

  // Clear and then set the ValueProperty to trigger a change notification.
  // This is necessary because we were editing a copy (in case the ValueProperty holds a value type). 
  // This is not necessary for types tha implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
  // However, we can't rely that the type raises the PropertyChanged event for the changed property.
  // We would need to inspect the property set() for a related method call using an IL inspector
  // in order to be able to identify if the property raises the PropertyChanged event.
  // This brute force solution may cause some PropertyChanged noise (the original property change and the edited type change).
  private void OnEditedInstanceChanged()
    => this.ValuePropertyBindingExpression.UpdateSource();
}
```

**Genric.xaml**
The default `Style` for the `TypeEditorControl`.
TODO: nice it up.

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>

  <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TypeEditorControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TypeEditorControl}">
          <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

            <StackPanel>

              <!-- The title -->
              <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding EditedTypeName}"
                         FontWeight="Bold"
                         FontSize="14" />

              <!-- Property view -->
              <TreeView ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding MemberItems}">
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                  <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="local:PropertyItem"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding NestedMembers}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullyQualifiedTypeName}"
                                 Margin="0,0,4,0" />
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                 TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                 Width="200" />
                      <TextBox x:Name="ValueDisplay"
                               Visibility="Collapsed"
                               Text="{Binding Value}"
                               Width="500" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NestedMembers.Count}"
                                   Value="0">
                        <Setter TargetName="ValueDisplay"
                                Property="Visibility"
                                Value="Visible" />
                      </DataTrigger>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
              </TreeView>
            </StackPanel>
          </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

### Usage Example

**Data.cs**
The example input data struct.

```cs
public struct Data
{
  public string? TextValue { get; set; }
  public Point Location { get; set; }

  public Data(string? text, Point location)
  {
    this.TextValue = text;
    this.Location = location;
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <local:TypeEditorControl IsEditReadOnlyMembersAllowed="False"
                           Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataItem}" />
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public Data DataItem
  {
    get => (Data)GetValue(DataItemProperty);
    set => SetValue(DataItemProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty DataItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "DataItem",
    typeof(Data),
    typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataItem = new Data("Initial text", new Point(100, 500));
  }
}
```

I highly recommend implementing input validation. Or at least check numeric input for overflows.

Comment: You Sir are a Legend. The amount of efferot you put into this is incredible.
I have put it into operation and for the first time ever a stack overflow response of this complexity worked first try for me! (after Upgrading the LanguageVersion because i apperantly lived under a rock, degugging some minor issues, struggeling with a faulty gernic.xaml and so on)

I am very thankfull and happy to hand you over my hard earned reputition! Bounty deserved.

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation! The reputation points are not like a salary, but thanks anyway. I aprreciate it ;) I had a property viewer at hand. This includes the complete tree view generation. So I only had to add the updating part including the final conversion.

Comment: After reviewing, I decided to refactor and improve the `GenericUnboxingValueConverter`. It used to make the generic static `UnboxConverter.Unbox` method every time the `IValueConverter.ConvertBack` was invoked. These recurring costs of reflection are avoidable. Now, the `GenericUnboxingValueConverter` stores the dynamically created `MethodInfo`  of the unboxing converter method in a static table. So, reflection is only required once for each converted type in a global scope. It's a small but important tweak.

Comment: Oh give me a bucket

Comment: @EmperorEto pardon me?

Answer (score 2):

So you generate a view capable of showing all structs and their properties recursively. And you have implemented `TextBox` controls for editing property values.
But when updating the nested struct properties, the changes in the `TextBoxes` do not propagate back to the struct.

```cs
textBox.TextChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    try
    {
        object value = Convert.ChangeType(textBox.Text, property.PropertyType);
        property.SetValue(instance, value);
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Handle conversion errors if needed
    }
};
```

That suggests that you need a method for the UI to interact with the data model such that changes in the UI (`TextBoxes`) update the corresponding properties in the data model (structs). [In WPF, this is typically achieved using two-way binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-8.0#direction-of-the-data-flow).

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/media/index/databinding-dataflow.png?view=netdesktop-8.0]

To achieve two-way binding with nested structures, you would need to make sure the changes in the UI propagate back to the data structure.
That can get complex with nested structs because structs are [value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types), and when you access a property of a struct, you are working with a *copy*, not the original instance.

To make this work, you typically need to replace the entire struct in the parent struct, after changing a nested property.
However, WPF's built-in binding does not handle this well for value types like structs.

So try and use *classes* instead of structs if possible, as classes are [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) and are more straightforward to bind.
If you must use structs, consider implementing [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) in a wrapper class that holds the struct and notifies the UI when a property changes. That way, you can bind to the wrapper class instead of directly to the struct.
Make sure every time a property within the struct changes, the entire struct is replaced in the parent object, triggering the `PropertyChanged` event for the parent property that holds the struct.

The `TextBox` controls should be bound to properties that notify the UI of changes.
Try and create a `StructWrapper<T>` class that holds a struct and implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```cs
public class StructWrapper<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged where T : struct
{
    private T _structInstance;

    public T StructInstance
    {
        get => _structInstance;
        set
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(_structInstance, value))
            {
                _structInstance = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You will need to modify your `StructEditor` control to work with this `StructWrapper` and make sure it updates the entire struct when a property changes. You might have to change your XAML to bind to the `StructWrapper`:

```xml
<local:StructEditor StructInstance="{Binding StructWrapperInstance.StructInstance, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

In your `StructEditor` [code-behind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/code-behind-and-xaml-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), you should replace the entire struct in the wrapper class when a nested property changes:

```cs
// That is a simplified example of how you might handle updates.
// You would need to expand this to handle nested properties properly.
textBox.TextChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    try
    {
        object value = Convert.ChangeType(textBox.Text, property.PropertyType);
        property.SetValue(instance, value);
        // Notify that the entire struct has changed.
        StructInstance = instance;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StructInstance));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Handle conversion errors if needed
    }
};
```

Finally, you will need to adjust your binding and property update logic to work with the `StructWrapper`. That may involve creating instances of `StructWrapper` for each struct you want to edit and making sure that your `StructEditor` control can handle these wrappers.

Do register the `StructWrapper<T>` class in XAML if you are using it as a binding source. You will likely need to create instances of the wrapper in your ViewModel or code-behind where you are preparing the data.

---

> The entire idea of my previous efforts was to make this a generic control that could work on the existing infrastructure and provide an interface to view and edit the protocol-packages.
> In my case, we are talking about hundreds of different struct types for different network protocols.
> I am aware of MVVM and the workings of bindings. I just don’t see how I could apply it to my problem, which is to work with structures with properties. That’s why I attempted to take the more traditional approach with textboxes and events.

So the need is for a generic control that can dynamically handle various struct types without the overhead of manually creating wrapper classes for each.

Given that structs are value types, any changes made to a nested struct's property will not affect the original struct unless the entire nested struct is set back to the parent struct: you would need to update the parent struct each time a nested property changes: You can use a stack or a list to keep track of the parent chain of properties. When you dive into nested structs, push the parent property info to the stack. When you go back up (when the recursion unwinds), pop the property info from the stack.
When a TextBox corresponding to a nested struct property is updated, use the stack to walk up to the root of the struct hierarchy, updating each struct along the way.

A *conceptual* representation of how you could handle the `TextChanged` event for nested structs would be:

```cs
textBox.TextChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    try
    {
        object value = Convert.ChangeType(textBox.Text, property.PropertyType);
        PropertyInfo[] parentProperties = ...; // The stack of parent properties leading to this property
        object rootInstance = ...; // The root instance of the struct hierarchy

        // Start from the leaf property and work back up to the root
        for (int i = parentProperties.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            PropertyInfo currentProperty = parentProperties[i];
            object currentInstance = currentProperty.GetValue(rootInstance);

            // Update the property in the current instance
            property.SetValue(currentInstance, value);

            if (i > 0)
            {
                // Set the updated instance to its parent
                PropertyInfo parentProperty = parentProperties[i - 1];
                object parentInstance = parentProperty.GetValue(rootInstance);
                parentProperty.SetValue(parentInstance, currentInstance);
            }
            else
            {
                // The top-level parent has been reached; update the root instance
                StructInstance = rootInstance;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle conversion errors if needed
    }
};
```

This is only a high-level conceptual guide, and will need to be fleshed out with the actual logic for managing the property stack and handling the root instance.

But the main idea remains to reflectively navigate the struct hierarchy, applying changes as needed. That would also mean that your `DisplayPropertiesRecursively` method will need to keep track of the property chain.

That... seems complex, due to the nature of structs in C#. And if the structs are large or deeply nested, performance may become a concern due to the reflection and repeated copying of struct instances.

---

> My problem is, once I go down recursively because its a `getbyValue` thing, I lose the reference to its parent...The "some kind of" part is what i am struggling with. I am used to work with classes and objects. Reflection makes this so much harder to see through...

You would need to create a way to track the parent-child relationship of the structs as you build the UI, so that when a property is updated, you can reconstruct the chain up to the root struct.
That involves keeping a breadcrumb trail as we recursively generate the UI for nested structs.

```cs
// A class to keep track of the parent chain and property info
public class PropertyChainLink
{
    public PropertyInfo PropertyInfo { get; set; }
    public object ParentInstance { get; set; }
}

// within the StructEditor class 

private void DisplayPropertiesRecursively(object instance, Stack<PropertyChainLink> parentProperties, int depth)
{
    Type type = instance.GetType();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
    {
        // generate UI elements 

        TextBox textBox = new TextBox
        {
            Width = 100,
            Text = property.GetValue(instance)?.ToString() ?? string.Empty
        };

        // Copy the current chain for the closure to capture
        var currentChain = new Stack<PropertyChainLink>(parentProperties.Reverse());

        textBox.TextChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            try
            {
                object value = Convert.ChangeType(textBox.Text, property.PropertyType);
                object currentInstance = instance;

                // Walk up the chain, updating each struct along the way
                while (currentChain.Count > 0)
                {
                    PropertyChainLink link = currentChain.Pop();
                    PropertyInfo currentProperty = link.PropertyInfo;

                    object updatedInstance = currentProperty.GetValue(link.ParentInstance);
                    property.SetValue(updatedInstance, value);
                    value = updatedInstance; // The parent becomes the new value to set
                }

                // Finally, update the root struct
                if (currentChain.Count == 0)
                {
                    this.StructInstance = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StructInstance));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle conversion errors if needed
            }
        };

        // Add the current property to the chain
        parentProperties.Push(new PropertyChainLink { PropertyInfo = property, ParentInstance = instance });

        // handle nested structs 

        // Remember to pop the property after the recursive call
        parentProperties.Pop();
    }
}

// Call this method initially with an empty stack
DisplayPropertiesRecursively(rootStructInstance, new Stack<PropertyChainLink>(), depth: 0);
```

Here, `PropertyChainLink` objects keep track of each property in the hierarchy and its parent instance. When a `TextBox` value changes, you would use this chain to walk back up the hierarchy and update each parent struct.

That implementation assumes that `OnPropertyChanged` is a method that raises the `PropertyChanged` event for the `StructInstance` property, which is necessary to notify the binding system in WPF that the root struct has been updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, but the entire idea of my previous efforts was to make this a generic control that could work on the existing infrastructure and provide an interface to view and edit the protocol-packages. In my case we are talking about hundreds of different struct types for different network protocols. 
I am aware of MVVM and the workings of bindings I just don’t see how I could apply it to my problem which is to work with structures with properties. That’s why I attempted to take the more traditional approach with textboxes and events.

Comment: I tried implementing the wrapper classes dynamically with reflection already however that didn’t get me where I wanted eigther

Comment: @DenisSchaf OK. I have edited the answer to propose an alternative to consider (but no complete solution, though).

Comment: Thank you for your edit. You have now exactly extracted the task I struggled with for hours… the recursive updating, tracking of the chain and all this is what I tried and failed to implement because I don’t work with objects like I am used to but rather I have to use reflection… the concept is clear, the execution hard…

Comment: @DenisSchaf I agree. I have cowardly left to the reader the implementation "as an exercise". I hope you will find one which does work.

Comment: Im on it... wish me luck!

Comment: I  saw your Update and will have a go tomorrow and see if i can get it to work!
I appreaciate your effernt and dedication to this matter

Answer (score 1):

The fact that "TextBox" has a .Tag property; as well as it's own .DataContext; and that you're using "code behind"; means that you should be able to manage any "backing structure" from those properties; via references, "codes", or delegates, or POCO's; "injected" via .Tag.

But as others have pointed out, you should create "classes" (proxies) for your "structures". The "object model" works best with classes. You load the "proxy" object graph; update that; then serialize back to the "structures".

I prefer ListViews; and templated Items. Same concept (.Tag), but now you also have "selection" capability. I add a "level" number; and an indent based on level number; and visibility based on level number; and I have a collapsible tree view. The same could be done with your StackPanel; but it's less fluid.